# Call a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 2 textboxes. I want to check that at least one textbox is filled, and if there is only one filled do some stuff and if there are both filled do something else. I found a `javascript` function that I think might help me but I don't know from where to call it.

here is the function

```
function verification() {
        var1= document.getElementById("form").value;
        var2= document.getElementById("form").value;
        if((var1 != "") && (var2 != ""))
        {
            // do what ever you want here.
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Fill at least one field");
        }

}
```

and the form:

```
<form id="form" action="start.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Person 1: <input type="text" name="person1" /> <br/>
Person 2: <input type="text" name="person2" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="verification()" />

Comment: please avoid inline javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function verification() {
        var1 = document.getElementById("person1").value;
        var2 = document.getElementById("person2").value;

        if((var1 != "") || (var2 != ""))
        {
            // do what ever you want here.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Fill at least one field");
            return false;
        }

}

<form id="form" action="start.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return verification();">
Person 1: <input type="text" id="person1" name="person1" /> <br/>
Person 2: <input type="text" id="person2" name="person2" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

And you should put your inline javascript to `js` file, so put that function `verification` to some `js` file.

Comment: The JS is still not right, `var1` and `var2` are assigned the same value, and not even the right one.

Comment: Great, now, to check that _at least one textbox is filled_, replace `&&` with `||` and I'll upvote :)

Comment: so there instead of "form" I should put "person1" and "person2"?

Comment: You missed elements IDs, so you had in `var1` and `var2` the same - the form value, whats undefined. You have to get element by id of specific input box. So I gave them `IDs` - `person1` and `person2`.

Comment: 'if((var1 != "") && (var2 != ""))' would require both fields to be filled in to be true.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the id `form` wont get the value of the input fields `person1` and `person2`. So you will have to modify your `var1` and `var2`.Also , as you  want to check if anyone of them is filled , you have to use `||` and not `&&`

HTML Modified:

```
<form id="form" action="start.php"  onsubmit="return verification()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Person 1: <input id="one" type="text" name="person1" /> <br/>
Person 2: <input id ="two" type="text" name="person2" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript modified:

```
function verification() {
        var1= document.getElementById("#one").value;
        var2= document.getElementById("#two").value;
        if((var1 != "") || (var2 != ""))
        {
            // do what ever you want here. 
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Fill at least one field");
            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: Functions has to have `()`, so `onclick="verification()"`. and also you missed `onclick="return verification()"`. Check my answer, already correct...

Comment: Also you should use `onsubmit`, because your function will be fired only if user click on the button, but user can press `ENTER` in the input fields... and then it will not be fired...

Comment: @Legionar now any problems??

Comment: `onsubmit` has to be as the `form` attribute, not `input` button... check my answer, then you will have the same answer as me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

html

```
<form id="form" action="start.php" method="post" onsubmit="return  verification();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Person 1: <input type="text" id="person1" name="person1" /> <br/>
Person 2: <input type="text" id="person2" name="person2" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript

```
function verification() {
        var1= document.getElementById("person1").value;
        var2= document.getElementById("person2").value;
        if((var1 == "") && (var2 == ""))
        {
            alert("Fill at least one field");

        }
        else
        {   if((var1 != "") && (var2 != "")){
             alert("both filled");
        }else{
        alert("only one field filled");
        }
        }

    return false;


}
```

Here I am returnig false(preventing form to submit) you can place it under if condition accoding to requirements.

[Corrected Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/g50Lfcfm/1/)

Comment: `verification()` will always return false, even fields are filled... so the form will be never submitted...

Comment: @Legionar I have mentioned that in my answer because the question dint specify when to submit the form

Answer (score 1):

OR use jQuery:

```js
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
  var var1 = $("input[name='person1']").val();
  var var2 = $("input[name='person2']").val();

  if (var1 != "" || var2 != "") {
    alert("All OK :)");
  } else {
    alert("Fill at least one field");
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("input[name='person1']").focus();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post">
  Person 1:
  <input type="text" name="person1" />
  <br/>Person 2:
  <input type="text" name="person2" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/cpuzfjpc/)